# match multiple variable in preg_match

Tags: php, variables, preg-match

Hi i really cant find the answer.
i got a couple variable that i wanna use in a preg_match but i only can use one variable.

my code is:

```
    function imagetoday(){
    global $imagetoday;
if(preg_match_all('/rain.png/', $imagetoday)){
    echo '<img src="assets/img/rain.png" class="img-responsive week" alt="Responsive image">';
    }

if(preg_match('/light_rain.png/', $imagetoday)){
    echo '<img src="assets/img/light_rain.png" class="img-responsive week" alt="Responsive image">';
    }


if(preg_match('/partly_cloudy.png/', $imagetoday)){
    echo '<img src="assets/img/partly_cloudy.png" class="img-responsive week" alt="Responsive image">';
    }
}
```

i tried to use

```
if(preg_match('/light_rain.png/', $imagetoday, $imageday2, imageday3, $imageday4)){
echo '<img src="assets/img/light_rain.png" class="img-responsive week" alt="Responsive image">';
}
```

but doesnt work can someone help me please? thanks!

Comment: That's not how `preg_match()` 's arguments work. Read [the docs](http://php.net/preg_match) on its definition. // You're not actually using regular expressions in this example; you're just doing a simple string search, for which something like [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) would likely suffice. // If you want to combine regular expressions, learn about using the pipe symbol `|` ([alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)).

Comment: What is it, exactly, you're trying to accomplish? See if a certain string exists in any of several different variables?

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
if (preg_match('/(?:(?:light_)?rain|partly_cloudy)\.png/', $imagetoday, $match)) {
    echo '<img src="assets/img/' . $match[0]
       . '" class="img-responsive week" alt="Responsive image">';
}
```